# Prove a matrix equality

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the square matrix

$$ J = \begin{bmatrix}
        \lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \ddots & \cdots \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, prove that $f(J)$ is given by the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        f(\lambda) & \dfrac{f'(\lambda)}{1!} & \dfrac{f''(\lambda)}{2!} & \cdots & \dfrac{f^{(n-2)}(\lambda)}{(n-2)!} & \dfrac{f^{(n-1)}(\lambda)}{(n-1)!}\\[1em]
        0 & f(\lambda) & \dfrac{f'(\lambda)}{1!} & \cdots & \dfrac{f^{(n-3)}(\lambda)}{(n-3)!} & \dfrac{f^{(n-2)}(\lambda)}{(n-2)!} \\[1em]
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & f(\lambda) & \dfrac{f'(\lambda)}{1!} \\[1em]
        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & f(\lambda) \\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

#### Try

First, we can find the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $\lambda$ and that is

$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{ f^{(k)}( \lambda) (x-\lambda)^n }{k!}  $$

Now, we have

$$ f(J) = \sum \frac{ f^{(k)} (\lambda) ( J-\lambda I)^k }{k!}$$

Now, notice that $J- \lambda I $ is the matrix with ones in the upper diagonal and when we take powers of this matrix, the ones move to the right . That is,

$$ (J - \lambda I)^k = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & I_{n-k} \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

as long as $k \leq n-1 $ and $0$ otherwise, so we can write

$$ f(J) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{ f^{(k)}(\lambda) I_{n-k} }{k!} $$

and I think this gives the result. Am I correct? Also, what is the motivation behind this exercise?

Comment: The last summation with different size matrices $I_{n-k}$ looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a another way you could do it:

- write the matrix of the linear operator $D: \mathbb{P}_{\leq N} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{\leq N}$, the derivative of a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{P}_{\leq N}$ of degree at most $N$, with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{1, x, x^2, ..., x^{N} \}$
- now, composition of linear operators can be viewed by multiplying representative matrices you can deduce (and prove by induction) the matrix for $D^K=D \circ D \circ ...\circ D$ $K$ times.
- now, deduce a general formula for $J^n$ and prove it via induction (use the binomial expression of $(1+\lambda)^n$)
- do the necessary algebra and you're done

A motivation behind this exercise could be found in Jordan's canonical form, which can help you, for example, to find analytical solutions to linear systems of ordinary differential equations.